# html, Force elements next to each other, even if cut off by scroll parent

Tags: html, css

I would like a series of elements to be next to each other inside a window with scrollbars. However, they keep moving to the next line instead.

I made a js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/922J5/

Note that I do not know the height of the children.

```
<div id = "parent">
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
</div>

#parent{overflow:scroll;
        width:200px;}

.child{
    background:red;
    margin:5px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add whitespace nowrap to the parent

```
#parent{overflow:scroll;
        width:200px;
    white-space:nowrap;}

.child{
    background:red;
    margin:5px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Updated code.

Comment: I'm not looking for all the children to be visible. I need them to have a set width and then for the parent's scrollbar to be activated.